# Almost Sure Convergence and Infimum

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

For

### $\alpha >0$

,

let

### $\left \{ {X_{n}}^{(\alpha )} \right \}_{n\geq 1}$

be a sequence of independent random variables such that

### $P({X_{n}}^{(\alpha )} = 1) = \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}} = 1 - P({X_{n}}^{(\alpha )} = 0)$

Let

### $S = \left \{ \alpha >0 :{X_{n}}^{(\alpha )} \overset{a.s}{\rightarrow} 0, n\rightarrow \infty \right \}$

Here I have to find

### $inf$ $S$

Now , I can understand from the above , that

### $E({X_{n}}^{(\alpha )}) = \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}}$

and

### $Var({X_{n}}^{(\alpha )}) = \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}} (1 - \frac{1}{n^{2\alpha}})$

Also, I think, I have to use Borel-Cantelli lemma . But Do not know, how to start with the problem .

Answer (score 1):

Can you decide if the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X_n^{(\alpha)}>0)$ converges or diverges?  With that knowledge in hand you can apply Borel-Cantelli.